# Activating Maven profile using system properties

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-profiles

I'm working on a project that uses Maven profiles to differentiate between environment-specific configurations. I'm running version **3.0.5**. The goal is to be able to specify the environment by passing a system property to the initial run command from the shell that corresponds to an activation property, like so:

**pom.xml**

```
<profiles>
   ...
    <profile><!-- Local Dev Environment -->
        <id>local</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>environment</name>
                <value>local</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            ...
        </properties>
    </profile><!-- End Local Dev Environment -->
    ...
</profiles>
```

**Startup Command**

`mvn exec:java -Denvironment=local`

However, the profile isn't activated (confirmed using `help:active-profiles`, which produces no output). I'm pretty noobish with Maven, but shouldn't this work?

It's my understanding that running `mvn` with the `-D` option allows me to set *system properties* (in this case: `environment` should equal `local`) which are then cross-referenced with the POM by Maven when running the application to determine which profile's activation criteria are met (per the required `activation properties`), and then running the application with those profiles active. Is there something that I'm not grokking here?

Answer (score 0):

I've got a POM here for a small test app with a test suite. I've included your profile and set a property to skip the tests.

I can activate the profile (and skip the tests) using 2 different methods:

```
mvn clean package -Plocal
```

or

```
mvn clean package -Denvironment=local
```

I haven't used the `exec` plugin before, I'm just looking at it now, but I don't think it should change the profile behaviour.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile><!-- Local Dev Environment -->
            <id>local</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>environment</name>
                    <value>local</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
            </properties>
        </profile><!-- End Local Dev Environment -->
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: I should've mentioned in the original question that I tried activating the profile directly using `-P` and that was also unsuccessful, which leads me to think there's either something up with my POM or something weird with my Maven installation.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a sample POM that works for me, I haven't tried it with the `exec` plugin however.